# CSS Transition opacity not effecting with rgba color

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

Why `opacity` transition is not effecting on `hover`, if i just put opacity separately as `.4` in text `class` it works, but it doesn't work with `rgba opacity`.

```css
ul {
  list-style:none
}

li {
  padding-bottom:15px;
 }
.text {
  color:rgba(13,19,13,.4); // here is initial opacity .4
  transition: opacity 2s cubic-bezier(.4,1,.2,1);
}

.text:hover {
  opacity:.9
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this element `<href=""a />` mean?

Comment: There is a difference between color opacity and opacity you are mixing them

Comment: Change the opacity/alpha on the actual rgba value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `color` for transition, once you change opacity within color attribute

```css
ul {
  list-style:none
}

li {
  padding-bottom:15px;
  font-size: 2em;
 }
.text {
  color:rgba(13,19,13,.4);
  transition: color 2s  cubic-bezier(.4,1,.2,1);
}

.text:hover {
  color: rgba(13,119,13,.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><span class="text">Item</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="text">Item</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="text">Item</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="text">Item</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="text">Item</span></a></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, in .text class give seperate properety for opacity.

```css
ul {
  list-style:none
}

li {
  padding-bottom:15px;
 }
.text {
  color:rgba(13,19,13,0.4);
  transition: opacity 2s cubic-bezier(.4,1,.2,1);
}

.text:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:rgba(13,19,13,0.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul>
    <li><href=""a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><href=""a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><href=""a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><href=""a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><href=""a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but, i am saying this works i have already mentioned in my question, i want why it is not working with rgba opacity.

Comment: I have edited my solution

Comment: I won't work if you give color opacity in text class and change element opacity in .hover state

Comment: So you have to use any of method shown in my snippets above

Answer (score 0):

Using `opacity` only rather then `color` opacity

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.text {
  opacity: .4;
  transition: opacity 2s cubic-bezier(.4, 1, .2, 1);
}

.text:hover {
  opacity: .9
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Using `color` `opacity`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.text {
  color: rgba(13, 19, 13, .4);
  transition: color 2s cubic-bezier(.4, 1, .2, 1);
}

.text:hover {
  color: rgba(13, 19, 13, .9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li>
      <href="" a /><span class="text">Item</span></li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks your demo not working, i don't see any transition effect on hover.

Comment: @jsduniya Sorry my bad did't remember to change opacity transition to color in color rgba hover case, Update my ans please check

Answer (score 0):

use the `color` property on transition and on `:hover` use `color:rgba(13,19,13,0.9);`

```css
ul {
  list-style:none
}

li {
  padding-bottom:15px;
 }
.text {
  color:rgba(13,19,13,0.4);
  transition: color 2s cubic-bezier(.4,1,.2,1);
}

.text:hover {
  color:rgba(13,19,13,0.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" /><span class="text">Item</span></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```